# Automatically capitalize macro output if used after a period

Tags: luatex, punctuation, automation, capitalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect beginning of a sentence in a macro for capitalization](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4834/detect-beginning-of-a-sentence-in-a-macro-for-capitalization)

Is it possible to write a macro that is able to determine if it is used at the beginning of a sentence? For example, imagine

```
\def\location{street}
...
This \location is nice. \location has its charm.
```

A simple and silly one, but anyway, you get the idea. I want the second street to be "Street." How would one do this? I am using `lualatex`, so if only a lua-specific solution is possible, I'd be happy with it. If it is not possible then I would have to do it manually, but that would be a lot of work in my text :-(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A quick test on `\spacefactor` works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\location}{%
  \ifnum\spacefactor=3000
    \expandafter\MakeUppercase\fi%
  street}
\begin{document}
This \location\ is nice. \location\ has its charm.
\end{document}
```

The `\spacefactor` differs depending on the preceding punctuation: `3000` after a period.

Since I'm unfamiliar with `\spacefactor`, I'm not sure how robust it is.

Comment: That's really nice, it fails, if `\frenchspacing` is set though. With `nonfrenchspacing` set before `ifnum` it seems to work with `frenchspacing` too.

Comment: Ha! And I was thinking that this was nearly impossible within LaTeX and required perhaps some lua magic!