# \autocap command is not working

Tags: capitalization

The following command is just a shortcut to avoid me to write two very long words I use often. I would like to capitalize the first letter of the first word at the beginning of a sentence.

```
\newcommand{\es}{\autocap{e}dslqk dlqsmd}
```

However `\es text.` (i.e. the command at the beginning of a sentence) does not print `Edslqk dlqsmd` but `edslqk dlqsmd`.

How can I capitalize this letter automatically?

Comment: Can you expand your code to a [compilable minimal example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html), so we all have the same basis of knowledge?

Comment: `\MakeUpperCase`?

Comment: `\autocap` is a `biblatex` command and as such only works if it is within the scope of `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker (that tracker is only working *within* citations and the bibliography). Automatically capitalising words depending on their position in the text is quite a difficult job (there have been questions about that here before, I think, with - if at all - quite complicated solutions).

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4834/35864 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2818119.

Comment: @HarishKumar: not really :) It is more likely a suggestion: if it works the OP itself can post an answer that I will be happy to upvote.

Comment: TeX can't read English or any other language. It has no notion of *beginning of sentence* that could be exploited. `biblatex` has `\autocap`, but this command is used in a very controlled environment, where everything has been split up into small pieces.