# A macro that behaves differently at start of sentence

Tags: macros

I am using a macro to represent a certain term, e.g:

```
\newcommand{\agt}{the agent}
```

(I use this macro so that it is easier to change the term in the future, if needed).

Is it possible to change the macro so that, in the beginning of a sentence, it will print "The agent" with capital T?

Comment: The linked question proposes a workaround which covers some of the cases but will also have exceptions where it doesn't work (e.g. beginning of a paragraph).  The problem you are describing (detect the beginning of a sentence) is, from a computer science perspective, a really hard one!  So it is not surprising to me that the solution is hackish and incomplete.  Mandatory XKCD: https://xkcd.com/1425/

Comment: If you're interested in a LuaLaTeX-based solution, please see [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400893/5001) I posted under the older query, [Detect beginning of a sentence in a macro for capitalization](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4834/5001).