# context-sensitive macro: look behind?

Tags: macros, tex-core

I try to fine-tune a macro depending on whether it is following a specific character/text. E.g.,

```
This is it! \great! Wait, what is \great?
```

should become

```
This is it! Grrreeeaaat! Wait, what is great?
```

because the first occurence of `\great` was after an exclamation mark, the second just in the middle of the sentence.

So I think I need something like a *look behind* but couldn't find anything except for `\lastbox`. Isn't there something like `\pastlet` complementing `\futurelet`, which allows checking for the next character, i.e. a look ahead?

Comment: Yo are probably much more likely to get help if you provide a full example of what you are doing. In what context this is used, etc.

Comment: I am still just playing around and want to see what I can do. A possible use could be `\MakeUppercase` after a period.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the current space factor code. I also load `amsthm` because

```
\documentclass{article}

% not needed if amsthm is loaded
\def\frenchspacing{\sfcode`\.1006\sfcode`\?1005\sfcode`\!1004%
  \sfcode`\:1003\sfcode`\;1002\sfcode`\,1001 }
%%%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\afterbigpunctornot}{%
  \ifnum\spacefactor>\sfcode`:
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\great}{\afterbigpunctornot{G}{g}reat}

\begin{document}

This is it. \great! Wait, what is \great?

This is it! \great! Wait, what is \great?

This is it? \great! Wait, what is \great?

This is it, \great! Wait, what is \great?

This is it; \great! Wait, what is \great?

This is it: \great! Wait, what is \great?

\frenchspacing

This is it. \great! Wait, what is \great?

This is it! \great! Wait, what is \great?

This is it? \great! Wait, what is \great?

This is it, \great! Wait, what is \great?

This is it; \great! Wait, what is \great?

This is it: \great! Wait, what is \great?

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is that the colon has the highest space factor code among all non “big” punctuation marks. We have to redefine `\frenchspacing` because the default definition just sets all space factor codes to 1000.

If you need the change only after the exclamation mark, we have to set its space factor code to a unique one.

```
\documentclass{article}

% not needed if amsthm is loaded
\sfcode`!=\numexpr\sfcode`!+1\relax

\def\frenchspacing{\sfcode`\.1006\sfcode`\?1005\sfcode`\!1004%
  \sfcode`\:1003\sfcode`\;1002\sfcode`\,1001 }
%%%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\afterexclamation}{%
  \ifnum\spacefactor=\sfcode`!
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\great}{\afterexclamation{Grrrr}{g}reat}

\begin{document}

This is it! \great! Wait, what is \great?

This is it. \great! Wait, what is \great?

This is it? \great! Wait, what is \great?

This is it, \great! Wait, what is \great?

This is it; \great! Wait, what is \great?

This is it: \great! Wait, what is \great?

\frenchspacing

This is it! \great! Wait, what is \great?

This is it. \great! Wait, what is \great?

This is it? \great! Wait, what is \great?

This is it, \great! Wait, what is \great?

This is it; \great! Wait, what is \great?

This is it: \great! Wait, what is \great?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
 \sfcode`\!=1001
 \newcommand\great{\ifnum\spacefactor=1001 Grrreeeaaat\else great\fi}
 \begin{document}
 This is it! \great! Wait, what is \great?
 \end{document}
```

[image]

See also [Detect beginning of a sentence in a macro for capitalization](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4834/detect-beginning-of-a-sentence-in-a-macro-for-capitalization)

Comment: This really is GREAAAAT!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes apart that I used an outdated screenshot ;-(. (One shouldn't change code in the last minute).

Comment: You can always change the code to match the screenshot. ;-)