# How can I condition on the last token?

Tags: macros, conditionals, token-lists

I would like to write a command `\foo` which, for the sake of simplicity, does just one thing, which is make sure its argument ends with a dot. Thus both `foo{hello world}` and `foo{hello world.}` expand to `hello world.` (or equivalent).

How do I do this? Is there some kind of "if-last-token" conditional I could use?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for a command that adds punctuation if not explicitly given in the argument?

Comment: For punctuation marks in particular there are good tricks to achieve this, but they may be impractical for other uses. I saw an answer by [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) about this a few days ago, maybe I can find it. Here its is: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4834/35864

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define a `\stripdot` command, which does the opposite of what you asked for - stripping a final "." - in two lines using only TeX primitives:

```
\def\stripdot#1{\stripdotA#1\end.\end!{#1}} 
\def\stripdotA#1.\end#2!#3{\ifx!#2!#3\else#1\fi}
```

given this command, defining `\foo` is now trivial:

```
\def\foo#1{\stripdot{#1}.}
\foo{Hello world.}

\foo{Hello world}

\bye
```

Comment: Cool! You can use this for implementing a test for trailing dots where `\end` is the only sentinel-token that must not occur in the argument. ;-)

Comment: \stripdot might strip one level of braces: \edef\test{\stripdot{{In Braces?}.}}{\tt\meaning\test}\bye – Ulrich Diez 53 mins ago

Comment: @wipet, Do you have any idea why sharelatex's compiler doesn't like this code?

Comment: What says log file? Maybe sharelatex is only LaTeX specific...

Answer (score 4):

I suspect this is an XY-question. Anyway, here's an expandable solution (add to the tests as needed).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}
 {
  \str_case_x:nnF { \tl_item:fn { #1 } { -1 } }
   {
    {.}{Ends~with~period}
    {,}{Ends~with~comma}
    {?}{Ends~with~question~mark}
   }
   {No~punctuation}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_item:nn { f }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\withperiod}{This ends with a period.}

\newcommand{\noperiod}{This doesn't end with a period}

\begin{document}

\foo{This ends with a period.} (period)

\foo{\withperiod} (period)

\foo{This ends with a comma,} (comma)

\foo{This ends with a question mark?} (question mark)

\foo{Foo} (no punctuation)

\foo{\noperiod} (no punctuation)

\edef\test{\foo{\withperiod}}\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a possibly more useful implementation: if the argument ends with `.!?`, nothing is added, otherwise a period is added.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}
 {
  \str_case_x:nnF { \tl_item:fn { #1 } { -1 } }
   {
    {.}{#1}
    {?}{#1}
    {!}{#1}
   }
   {#1.}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_item:nn { f }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\withperiod}{This ends with a period.}

\newcommand{\noperiod}{This will end with a period}

\begin{document}

\foo{This ends with a period.}

\foo{\withperiod}

\foo{This ends with an exclamation mark!}

\foo{Does this end with a question mark?}

\foo{This will end with a period}

\foo{\noperiod}

\edef\test{\foo{\withperiod}}\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is also a classical way to do this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm} % for \@addpunct

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{#1\@addpunct{.}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\withperiod}{This ends with a period.}

\newcommand{\noperiod}{This will end with a period}

\begin{document}

\foo{This ends with a period.}

\foo{\withperiod}

\foo{This ends with an exclamation mark!}

\foo{Does this end with a question mark?}

\foo{This will end with a period}

\foo{\noperiod}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apart from [Detect beginning of a sentence in a macro for capitalization](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4834/35864) you could also use `\IfEndWith` from the `xstring` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\IfEndWith{#1}{.}{#1}{#1.}}
\begin{document}
\foo{hello world}

\foo{hello world.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to look at the sequence of tokens that forms the argument of `\foo` unexpanded, you can add a trailing dot to that argument and then run a loop which removes dot-delimited arguments until removing another dot-delimited argument would yield emptiness.

Then examine whether the remaining dot-delimited argument is empty.
If so, the last token of the argument of `\foo` was a dot.
If not so, the last token of the argument of `\foo` was not a dot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%......................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
%%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}\@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's last token is a dot:
%%......................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherTrailingDot{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       does have a last token which is a dot>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       does not have a last token which is a dot>}%
%%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherTrailingDot[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\@secondoftwo}%
  {\UD@CheckWhetherTrailingDotGobbleToDotLoop{#1.}}%
  {\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}\@firstoftwo}%
  {\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}\@secondoftwo}%
}%
%%%%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherTrailingDotGobbleToDotLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull
  \expandafter{\UD@CheckWhetherTrailingDotGobbleToDot#1}{%
     \UD@CheckWhetherTrailingDotFork{.}#1%
  }{%
     \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherTrailingDotGobbleToDotLoop
     \expandafter{\UD@CheckWhetherTrailingDotGobbleToDot#1}%
  }%
}%
%%%%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherTrailingDotGobbleToDot{}
\long\def\UD@CheckWhetherTrailingDotGobbleToDot#1.{}
%%%%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherTrailingDotFork{}%
\long\def\UD@CheckWhetherTrailingDotFork#1.{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\@gobble#1}%
}%
%%%%
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherTrailingDot{#1}{#1}{#1.}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

With \verb|\foo| an empty argument is recogniced as an argument
that dose not have a trailing dot:

\verb|\foo{}|: \foo{}

\verb*|X\foo{ }X|: X\foo{ }X

\verb|\foo{.}|: \foo{.}

\verb|\foo{Bla. Bla.}|: \foo{Bla. Bla.}

\verb|\foo{Bla. Bla}|: \foo{Bla. Bla}

\verb|\foo{Bla. {Bla.}}|: \foo{Bla. {Bla.}}

\verb|\foo{hello world}|: \foo{hello world}

\verb|\foo{hello world.}|: \foo{hello world.}

With \verb|\foo| dots nested in braces will not count as trailing dots as
in this case the last token of the argument is not a dot but a closing brace:

\verb|\foo{hello world{.}}|: \foo{hello world{.}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The gist of the following solution, which is much better, comes from the [answer of wipet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442231/118714) :

Choose a `<sentinel token>` which must not occur within the argument to examine (unless nested in braces).

Append `<sentinel token>.<sentinel token><delimiter>` (`<delimiter>` other than `.` and other than `<sentinel token>` and other than `.<sentinel token>`) behind the argument to examine before fetching a first argument delimited by `.<sentinel token>` and fetching a second argument delimited by `<delimiter>`.

In case the last token of the argument to examine is a dot, that dot and the first `<sentinel token>` from the appended sequence form the delimiter for that first argument to fetch, and the second argument is not empty but holds the sequence `.<sentinel token>`.

In case the last token of the argument to examine is not a dot, the dot from the appended sequence and the second `<sentinel token>` from the appended sequence form the delimiter for that first argument to fetch, and the second argument is empty.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Wipet@CheckWhetherTrailingDot[1]{%
  \Wipet@CheckWhetherTrailingDotA#1\end.\end!%
}%
\newcommand\Wipet@CheckWhetherTrailingDotA{}%
\long\def\Wipet@CheckWhetherTrailingDotA#1.\end#2!{%
  \ifx!#2!\expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi
}%
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \Wipet@CheckWhetherTrailingDot{#1}{#1}{#1.}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

With \verb|\foo| an empty argument is recogniced as an argument
that dose not have a trailing dot:

\verb|\foo{}|: \foo{}

\verb*|X\foo{ }X|: X\foo{ }X

\verb|\foo{.}|: \foo{.}

\verb|\foo{Bla. Bla.}|: \foo{Bla. Bla.}

\verb|\foo{Bla. Bla}|: \foo{Bla. Bla}

\verb|\foo{Bla. {Bla.}}|: \foo{Bla. {Bla.}}

\verb|\foo{hello world}|: \foo{hello world}

\verb|\foo{hello world.}|: \foo{hello world.}

With \verb|\foo| dots nested in braces will not count as trailing dots as
in this case the last token of the argument is not a dot but a closing brace:

\verb|\foo{hello world{.}}|: \foo{hello world{.}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What's embarrassing for me is that when writing my first solution, which is cumbersome, I did not remember [the method shown by wipet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442231/118714) although it is well-known.

E.g., for several years in the early nineties the late ***Michael Downes*** presented a series of TeX macro programming challenges he called ***Around the Bend***.

More information about this can be found on CTAN at https://ctan.org/pkg/around-the-bend.

The document holding all programming challenges and answers can be found at
https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/challenges/AroBend/AroundTheBend.pdf .

In Challenge 15 – *Space removal*, section 15.2.3 – *Some remarks about the domain of the problem*, on page 66, [the method shown by wipet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442231/118714) is exhibited and explained. The only difference is that there the method is used for trimming a trailing space instead of trimming a trailing dot:

> In the previous posting I discussed the method of removing a trailing
>   space by scanning for a token pair `<space><bizarre>` [...]

Comment: +1 For a solution "from first principles" using no packages... :-)

Comment: @einpoklum  [wipet's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442231/118714) is also a solution "from first principles using no packages" and much better.  :-)

Comment: ... @wipet posted it after you posted yours; and I wouldn't downvote you of course. I did accept his solution though.

Answer (score 1):

This uses `listofitems` to accomplish the task, and can be set up to intercept multiple qualifying end-punctuation (here `.`, `?` and `!`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \setsepchar{.||?||!}% <-- LIST ALL PUNCTUATION THAT QUALIFES AS ENDING
  \readlist\myarg{#1}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\myarg[]{%
    \x%
    \ifnum\xcnt=\listlen\myarg[]\relax%
      \if\relax\x\relax\else.\fi%
    \else%
      \myargsep[\xcnt]%
    \fi%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\foo{Hello world}\par
\foo{Hello world.}\par
\foo{Stop. This. Now}\par
\foo{Stop. This. Now.}\par
\foo{Stop. This. Now!}\par
\foo{well...that is that}\par
\foo{well...that is that.}\par
\foo{well...how is that?}
\end{document}
```

[image]