# Why can't cleveref determine if the reference is at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I was reading the documentation on the `cleveref` package, which can be found [here](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf), when I stumbled upon a side remark on page six (can be found in the paragraph for `\Cref`), which says

> As it is very difficult³ for LATEX to determine whether a cross-reference appears at the beginning of a sentence or not, [...]
>
> ³ Actually, very likely impossible!

(Changed the original Latex sign generated by `\LaTeX` to LATEX)

I'd like to know why this is the case?

Comment: Just try to automatically detect the beginning of a sentence in any programming language keeping in mind that there are abbreviations ending with a period, dots at other positions in the sentence and multiple languages and you will see that text processing can be quite difficult for these nuances.

Comment: Additionally, standard (La)TeX has no way to check what the last processed token was. So when the `\Cref` is executed, there's no simple way to check whether the character before it was a period or other punctuation mark. You could make punctuation marks macros itself that check if the *following* token is `\Cref`, but this is likely to cause trouble in other places and wouldn't be very reliable.

Comment: What one needs is a of pre-processor approach, in which one examines the input stream as follows. (For simplicity, assume that each paragraph, or at least each sentence, is contained in a single line of input.) Then, every time the string `\cref` is encountered in the input stream, check if it occurs at the very start of a line or is preceded by a sentence-ending punctuation mark followed by whitespace. If one of these conditions is true, determine that `\cref` occurs at the start of a sentence. But this would impose a horrible amount of computing overhead, grossly slowing compilation.

Comment: @Mico I can understand the idea and the consequences of the approach you suggested, but if I understand you correctly, it could be done, it's just that the consequences of such an approach outweigh the possible advantages, right?

Comment: A `\Cref` when I wrote `\cref`?  no, thanks ! For me is not  a problem of computing overhead, but that I hate  that the computer choose by me what to do after a period, like in " *E. coli* ", supposedly to gain time while typing, but in practice this kind of "AI" is useful only to waste your time while correcting the wrong uppercases and, if you are not careful, left them in the final document! Even if that AI could detect the end of a paragraph, or the end of a sentence (how?) I doubt that it could be a real benefit for the writer.

Comment: It is not so difficult to detect this (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4870/2388) (in many cases, not all) but the problem is that cleveref can't know if the document changes the sfcodes.

Comment: @Sito - I think the preprocessor-based approach I outlined could be done in principle. Basically, all instances of `\cref` that satisfy one of the criteria I mentioned would be replaced with `\Cref` "on the fly", and `cleveref` would not have to perform any extra work (since it doesn't know which instances of `\Cref` were there to begin with and which ones are on-the-fly replacements for `\cref`. I seriously doubt the usefulness of such an exercise, though. How difficult, really, is it to develop a habit of writing `\Cref` at the start of a sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based implementation of the preprocessor-based approach I outlined in the comments above. It replaces instances of `\cref` with `\Cref` (and of `\crefrange` with `\Crefrange`) if they occur either at the very start of a line of input or are preceded by a sentence-ending punctuation mark (`.`, `?`, or `!`) followed by one of more whitespaces. The main work is performed by the `cref2Cref` Lua function, which gets assigned to the `process_input_buffer` callback, thus acting as a preprocessor before TeX  starts its normal work.

The main, crucial assumption about the *input* is that there are no line-breaks inside sentences. If this assumption isn't satisfied, the approach is not guaranteed to work. A second, hopefully trivially-true, assumption is that only macros of the `cleveref` package start with the string `\cref`. If, for whatever reason, your code defines macros named `\crefx` or `\crefzzz`, be prepared for some unpleasant surprises. The approach also ignores the possibility that non-sentence-ending periods are followed immediately by `\cref`. Thus, a (highly questionable!) sentence fragment such as "Mr. and Mrs. \cref{fig:a} are pleased to announce" will trip up the algorithm. Do let me know if your document contains such passages...

The code used to generate the following screenshot loads the `hyperref` package and loads the `cleveref` package with the option `nameinlink` in order to make it easy for the eye to detect cross-references. Observe that two of the four instances of `\cref` were replaced with `\Cref` "on the fly".

[image]

Finally, note that `cleveref` itself does no extra work here: It only ever gets to see, and process, instances of `\cref` and `\Cref`. `cleveref` has no way of knowing which instances of `\Cref` and `\Crefrange` were provided by the author and which ones were created on-the-fly by the Lua function `cref2Cref`.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'gather' env.
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % optional
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function cref2Cref ( s )
   s = s:gsub ( "^\\cref", "\\Cref" )
   s = s:gsub ( "([%.%!%?])%s*\\cref" , "%1 \\Cref" )
   return s
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
%% Assign the Lua function to the 'process_input_buffer' callback:
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback( 
  "process_input_buffer" , cref2Cref , "cref2Cref" )}}

\begin{document}
%% Set up a few equations and figures.
\begin{gather} 
1+1=2 \label{eq:1} \\
2+2=4 \label{eq:2} \\
3+3=6 \label{eq:3} 
\end{gather}
\begin{figure}[h!] 
\caption{AAA} \label{fig:a} \smallskip
\caption{BBB} \label{fig:b} \smallskip 
\caption{CCC} \label{fig:c} 
\end{figure}

% Now generate a few cross-references.
Is this a cross-reference to \cref{eq:1}? \cref{eq:2,eq:3} show that\dots

\crefrange{fig:a}{fig:c} illustrate\dots\ As \crefrange{fig:b}{fig:c} demonstrate, \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! To respond to `How difficult, really, is it to develop a habit of writing \Cref at the start of a sentence?`: There is absolutely no problem in writing `\Cref` instead of `\cref` where necessary, it's just that I thought the problem was interesting and I was curious about the statement, that there probably doesn't exist a solution for the problem.  Once again, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Sito - You're most welcome. Do note that the maintained assumption about the input format can be quite strong. For sure, if someone's in the habit of inserting line breaks immediately before `\cref` and `\crefrange`, the method outlined above is simply not going to work correctly.