# Enumerate sentence beginning with square bracket

Tags: enumerate

In the enumerate environment, an item begins with "[Co]image is..."  LaTex interprets the square bracket as a customized bullet symbol. How can I write [ without this glitch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\relax` FTW:

```
\item\relax[Co]image
```

Answer (score 8):

This also works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item{}[Co]image
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image: Enumeration]

Comment: @tohecz You're right - it's gone... Thanks!

Comment: @tohecz FWIW, I'd already voted for your solution. However, I bet I would still use `{}` here because I'd never think to use `\relax` in a document - only in code. (Mostly, I want something done but nothing typeset as opposed to nothing done at all and `\myhellomacro{} bird! \myhellomacro\relax plane!` does right by bird but not by plane.)

Comment: And I would use ``\myhellomacro\ bird`` or `\myhellomacro\@ bird` ;)

Comment: @tohecz I used to use `\myhellomacro\ bird` and then I read about some reason `\myhellomacro{} bird` is preferable. Although I cannot remember what the reason was. I've never come across `\@` - what does that do?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22564/11002

Comment: @tohecz Thanks. I even use that and didn't realise when you wrote it. (I type `etc\@.` to end a sentence and `etc.\ ` to not end one although presumably at least one of these is unnecessary.)

Answer (score 4):

You could also simply put a `{}` around the text.  .

[image]

### Notes:

- Adding an additional brace group is also a handy technique and useful for cases where you need to pass a parameter containing a `[]`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item {[Co]image}
\end{enumerate}
```