# What does backslash at sign mean in latex? \@

Tags: warnings

I'm writing a document and my latex code linter is telling me

```
missing `\@' before `.' in "ABC."
```

The linter only gives me this warning when there is a capital letter just before a period ending a sentence that precedes another sentence. What does this `\@` do? Putting it in my code doesn't seem to make any change to the document.

Minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
ABC. Hello.
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is `linter`? I get no warning using `pdflatex` or `latex`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `lint` is a syntax checker (for C) distinct from the C compiler. so by extension linting is syntax checking

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I know `lint`, but never heard of `linter`

Comment: this must be a duplicate, I'll see if I can find...

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22561/what-is-the-proper-use-of-i-e-backslash-at

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- good find.  just added it to "often referenced questions".