# Shrink space after colon without shrinking space after period

Tags: spacing, punctuation

When a colon is used to separate clauses in a sentence (rather than preceding a list), current typographic practice, and my preference, is to follow it with the same space as after a semicolon.

The LaTeX default `\nonfrenchspacing` violates that, making the space after a colon the same as after a period.

But `\frenchspacing`,while shrinking the space after a colon, unfortunately also shrinks the space after a period, which I do *not* want to do.

See this example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\nonfrenchspacing
\emph{nonfrenchspacing}
\smallskip

Spacing after; semicolon.

Spacing after: colon.

Spacing after. period

\bigskip

\frenchspacing
\emph{frenchspacing}
\smallskip

Spacing after; semicolon.

Spacing after: colon.

Spacing after. period

\end{document}
```

[image: Spacing after colon, semicolon, and period.]

How can I get all the following:

- space after a colon separating clauses the same as that after a semicolon; and
- space after a colon before a list retains the larger spacing from `\nonfrenchspacing`; and
- space after a period retains the larger spacing from `\nonfrenchspacing`?

Comment: The traditional (manual) approach is `Spacing after:\@ colon.` with the use of `\@`.

Comment: It seems that `\frenchspacing` doesn't respect the traditional French spacing *before* a colon or a semicolon (thin unbreakable space)…

Comment: @Bernard The names are a bit odd, to be honest. They only refer to the spacing *after* punctuation.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- I believe that "`\ `" (slash-space) is preferable.  See [What is the proper use of \@ (i.e., backslash-at)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22561)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for that link.  Learned something new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want that the space after a colon is the same as after a semicolon, tell TeX that the space factor codes of both are the same.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\nonfrenchspacing\sfcode`:=\sfcode`;
\emph{nonfrenchspacing}
\smallskip

Spacing after; semicolon.

Spacing after: colon.

Spacing after. period

\bigskip

\frenchspacing
\emph{frenchspacing}
\smallskip

Spacing after; semicolon.

Spacing after: colon.

Spacing after. period

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you won't be changing between “French spacing” and “non French spacing” (would you?), you can simply state

```
\sfcode`:=\sfcode`;
```

before `\begin{document}`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\sfcode`:=\sfcode`;

\begin{document}

Spacing after; x

Spacing after: x

Spacing after. x

\end{document}
```

[image]

TeXnical note. The space factors of semicolon, colon and period under `\nonfrenchspacing` are, respectively, 1500, 2000 and 3000. So it's a bit inaccurate to say that the space after a colon is the same as after a period.

Comment: But then how would I (temporarily) revert to my preferred wider space when a colon precedes a list?

Comment: @murray Does this make sense? Anyway, do `\newcommand{\colonlist}{:\spacefactor2000\relax\space\ignorespaces}` and use `\colonlist` in front of a list.

Comment: Yes, that works, thank you!