Uppercase & abbreviation dot in a field - string manipulation
I use a custom driver that contains the nameaddon field.
Below a wme:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@customa{test,
  author = {Author},
  nameaddon = {nameaddon},
  title = {Title},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%\DeclareDelimFormat*{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}    

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{customa}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \iffieldundef{nameaddon}{}{%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{nameaddon}}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
\cite{test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

If the content of nameaddon is an uppercase and abbreviated text, like
nameaddon = {NAMEADDON.}

the typesetting will contain an error (double 'dot' in the citation):

A possible solution is to write the contents of the field as follows:
nameaddon = {NAMEADDON\adddot}

but this does not satisfy me. I would like to avoid to insert \adddot directly into the .bib file. So I would like to find a way to automatically replaces the ending dot (if present) with the command \adddot.
In addition, I have two more curiosities:

Why does the problem occurs in nameaddon and not, for example, in the author field? Does it perhaps depend on the "Data Type" (Name list, Literal field)?
It can be checked, using the following bibliography item:

@customa{test,
  author = {AuthoR.},
  nameaddon = {nameaddoN.},
  title = {TitlE.},
  subtitle = {Subtitle},
}


Why does the problem occurs in the citation and not in the bibliography?

Finally, from the more general perspective...
It would be appropriate that within a field, an ending dot should always be considered an abbreviating dot, since all punctuation should never be entered as field content, but set via the appropriate commands (for example: redefining \newunitpunct; using \DeclareDelimFormat, etc.).

I don't have the time to investigate an automatic solution (and I also don't have the link handy that explains why the result in citations and the bibliography are different) right now, but for now please note that according to normal LaTeX rules the correct input here if the . in NAMEADDON. is supposed to be a sentence-ending full stop/period is nameaddon = {NAMEADDON\@.}. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22561/35864. This is the same in normal text.

In my case the dot meaning an abbreviation, but the syntax @.\isdot is necessary to have a correct typesetting in all possible situations (uppercase / lowercase text; different nametitledelim punctuation).

As you may guess, I need a general solution, because I am designing a bibliography style.

Still not a lot of time, sorry, but I think the difference between citations and bibliography is explained by results of the discussion in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/295.

I see that @Ulrike Fischer had posted a possible solution. However I note that the issue has been raised by many and that, probably, something will have to be done.

One solution might be a conditional that automatically replaces the ending dot (if present) with the command \adddot

Cleaned up comments a bit.

As discussed in the comments (and in particular in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/295 and linked issues) an actual solution is not going to be easy and I didn't have time (and probably won't have time in the next couple of days) to look into this in more detail (and even if I can find the time, it's unlikely I'll find a simple solution, last time I looked, there wasn't one).
But here is a fairly simple sourcemapping solution that just turns the . at the end of a field into an \adddot, so that it is definitely treated as an abbreviation dot.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=nameaddon,
            match=\regexp{\.\Z},
            replace=\string\\adddot]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{customa}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{nameaddon}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@customa{test,
  author    = {Author},
  nameaddon = {nameaddoN.},
  title     = {Title},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}



I had already used sourcemapping to manipulate the contents of the fields, wonder why it didn't occur to me. Thank you very much!

Could there be a reason for preferring, in the regular expression, the inclusion of the hexadecimal notation (\x2E) instead of the dot (.)?

@matteofg In this case I'm not aware of any problems with \., but then I'm not a RegExp or XML expert, so if you hit a roadblock and the hexadecimal solution works, by all means go for it and mention it here in the comments. The general rule with LaTeX is that you can break almost anything if you set your mind to it, but not all of the situations you may come up with to break something are going to occur naturally in many documents.

I found a solution with expl3 (of which I'm not at all an expert).
Below the wme:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@customa{test,
  author = {Author},
  nameaddon = {nameaddoN},
 %nameaddon = {nameaddoN.},
  title = {Title},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}

% Replace ending dot with \adddot
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \matteofg_if_lastchar_dot:n { p, T, F, TF }
  {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF
      { \str_item:nn { #1 }{ -1 } }
      {.}
      { \prg_return_true: }
      { \prg_return_false: }
  }
\cs_new:Nn \matteofg_replace_last_dot:n
  {
    \matteofg_if_lastchar_dot:nTF { #1 }
     { \tl_range:nnn { #1 } {1} {-2} \adddot }
     { #1 }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\mkreplacedot}{m}
 {
  \matteofg_replace_last_dot:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareFieldFormat[customa]{nameaddon}{\mkreplacedot{#1}}

%\DeclareDelimFormat*{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}    

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{customa}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \iffieldundef{nameaddon}{}{%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{nameaddon}}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
\cite{test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

At first sight it should work. I hope that an expl3 expert can give an opinion and, perhaps, improve the code.
