# Controlling space between two words in the body of text

Tags: spacing

In my thesis I'll have equations that are labelled (1) through to (20).

In the body of the text I'll refer to them as `Eq. (1),..., Eq. (20)`, for example. The problem is that LaTeX will change the spacing between `Eq.` and `(1)`, as it does with the spacing between any two separate words, in order to fill the margins. This looks ugly.

How do I fix this?

Comment: `Eq.~\ref{equationNUMBER}` might help

Comment: @PattaFeuFeu Not only it might help, it *is* the correct way to write. Please, supply an answer.

Comment: @egreg -- but a `~` (tie) won't keep the space uniform; it will only ensure that "Eq." is not separated from the number.  of course, that's the right thing to do, but not what is asked.  for that, a fixed space, either `\,` or `\;` would be better.  `\;` is defined only for math use, which is a nuisance, so maybe an explicit `\nobreak\kern.3em` would be preferable.

Comment: @barbarabeeton `~` is equivalent to `\nobreak\ ` which of course inserts a normal space (not affected by the space factor). IMO it's better that all spaces on a line have the same width. Probably Jase's problem is just due to the extended space after periods.

Comment: @egreg -- good point.  i concede.  (it's still morning here.)

Comment: I can't follow this discussion. Should I mark PattaFeuFeu's answer as correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Eq.~\ref{equationNUMBER}`, where `equationNUMBER` is the value you set for the equation’s `label`, does what you want. The tilde is a non-breaking space to ensure that the connected parts (Eq. and your reference) stay connected.

Comment: The answer should say that a space after a period is "usually" anlarged (indicating a sentence ending). Both `~` as well as `\ ` will produce a normal interword space (the former also preventing a line break).

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: Concerning the "usually" a reference to [Double space between sentences.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4705/double-space-between-sentences) might be helpful.

Comment: @Stephen yes that is a nice link for this

Comment: @FrankMittelbach ...and now I see that at the right below "Linked" exact that link is given. Nice to see the stackexchange software doing a good job, but embarrassing for me to not have seen that.

Comment: @Stephen I guess that was automatically added due to you mentioning it in the comment :-)

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: Hey, the software is "cheating" and getting ideas from comments? Then the code behind this is even better then already expected.