# Simplest way to typeset a double space

Tags: spacing

I have a very simple question.

Sometimes I need to put two spaces between letters or words, like this:

```
a a    %this is a single space
a  a   %this is a double space
```

I want the double space to be as if was a single space*2. What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Currently what I'm doing is

```
a\ \ a
```

but I'm under the impression this is not a clean way to achieve my goal

Comment: I don't know of a better way (may be `~~` if you don't want them to break), but why do you need that?

Comment: Related: [Double space between sentences](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4705/double-space-between-sentences).

Comment: Either `~~`, or call `\obeyspaces` inside a group and you don't have to worry about forcing it.

Comment: In the TeXbook source, Knuth sometimes does `<space><backslash><space>`; for instance `with the page break. \ (Deep breath.) \ You got that?` However, I don't see many cases where a double space is useful. Can you add an example?

Comment: @Manuel It is used as a graphical convention in some material I am contributing to (yeah, I know it's not the best convention)

Comment: @egreg yes I got It. As an example just imagine a list of letters or symbols, some are separated by a simple space, other by a double space (`A B C  J K`). Then you have the same with words. This does not happen in normal text, only in these "lists". Anyway all proposed solutions are better than what I was using, but `\obeyspaces` suits best my use case. Didn't know about it, thanks.

Comment: You could just use `\quad`.

Comment: If you only need it in that kind of lists… I think you should define a special command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The notion of a double space is very poorly defined and if you try to use it to denote any meaning to the reader it will be massively confusing. TeX is not a typewriter, spaces do not have fixed length they stretch and shrink to adjust words to help with line breaking so words which have a single space between them  in the source may already be separated by space that differ by a factor of two between lines that are tight and lines that are loose. a word space in 10pt computer modern is

```
\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
```

so anywhere between 2.2pt and 5pt.

So a double space on a tight line is smaller than a single space on a loose line.

Comment: I'm accepting this for the explanation but as I said in previous comments I'll use \obeyspaces for my problem

Answer (score 4):

You can use a doubled tilde `~~` to get two spaces. But maybe `\enskip` can help too or you define a command, like `\ds` (for double space) to be flexible in future if you want to change the width of the doubled space.

[image: spaces in TeX]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\ds}{~~}

\begin{document}
H H (normal Space)

H~~H (doubled Space with \verb+~~+, double Tilde)

H\ds H (doubled Space with userdefined \verb+\ds+)

H\enskip H (\verb+\enskip+)

H\quad H (\verb+\quad+)

H\qquad H (\verb+\qquad+)

H\hspace{5em} H (certain space with \verb+\hspace+)
\end{document}
```

---

If you need this only in special lists you may define a command taking the list as argument. I used `xparse` to define a command with a verbatim argument (type `v`) because `\newcommmand` will parse the argument and truncate the spaces before `\obeyspaces` can do its job.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{ \letterlist }{ v }
 {%
  {\obeyspaces#1}%
 }

\begin{document}
            A B  C   D E      F

\letterlist{A B  C   D E      F}
\end{document}
```

[image: use of \obeyspaces]

But the image shows that a single and a double space can be easily confused, so one may consider using other symbols to separate the list …