# Suppressing end-of-sentence spacing after period not working in beamer class?

Tags: beamer, spacing

Supposedly, LaTeX puts a double space after a `.` ([end of sentence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2236)), which can be suppressed by a following backslash `.\`.
However, this does not seem to work in LaTeX `beamer` class.
See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 

\title{Beispiel in \LaTeX}
\author{rotton}

\begin{document}

\section{Horizontale Abstände}

\begin{frame}{Punkttest}
Nach Punkt: Stets doppeltes Leerzeichen, unterdrücken mit \texttt{.\textbackslash} : \\
\textbf{Flattersatz, linksbündig} \\
Prof.\ Dr.\ rer.\ nat.\ habil.\ Müller und noch etwas Text bis zum Zeilenende \\
Prof. Dr. rer. nat. habil. Müller und noch etwas Text bis zum Zeilenende

\justifying
\textbf{Der Rest im Blocksatz} \\
Prof.\ Dr.\ rer.\ nat.\ habil.\ Müller und noch etwas Text bis zum Zeilenende \\
Prof. Dr. rer. nat. habil. Müller und noch etwas Text bis zum Zeilenende

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I thought this was due to the ragged-right alignment, but even with [`\justifying`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beamerposter/6nfR6q04ERc), those spaces do not change at all! 
[image: Horizontal spacing after period in beamer]
Can anyone explain this? Is it possible to obtain the default spacing behavior in `beamer`, and if, how?

Comment: This is as a result of using `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`. So yes, it's possible to obtain the default spacing behaviour in [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) after removing said package... :)

Comment: Ah, so this package option implicitly sets `\frenchspacing`? Is it possible to restore the default behavior somehow?
Nevermind, seems [I've found it.](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/1154/was-ist-french-spacing-was-macht-frenchspacing/1158)

Comment: You can issue `\nonfrenchspacing`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loading `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` issues `\frenchspacing`, which affects the spacing (effectively suppressing them) around certain punctuation. These include `.`, `?`, `!`, `:`, `;` and `,`. You can reverse this by issuing `\nonfrenchspacing`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 

\title{Beispiel in \LaTeX}
\author{rotton}

\begin{document}

\nonfrenchspacing

\section{Horizontale Abstände}

\begin{frame}{Punkttest}
Nach Punkt: Stets doppeltes Leerzeichen, unterdrücken mit \texttt{.\textbackslash} : \\
\textbf{Flattersatz, linksbündig} \\
Prof.\ Dr.\ rer.\ nat.\ habil.\ Müller und noch etwas Text bis zum Zeilenende \\
Prof. Dr. rer. nat. habil. Müller und noch etwas Text bis zum Zeilenende

\justifying
\textbf{Der Rest im Blocksatz} \\
Prof.\ Dr.\ rer.\ nat.\ habil.\ Müller und noch etwas Text bis zum Zeilenende \\
Prof. Dr. rer. nat. habil. Müller und noch etwas Text bis zum Zeilenende

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Double space between sentences.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4705/5764)

Comment: Got it. Does `\nonfrenchspacing` apply globally, or only from the point where it is inserted til the end of the document?

Comment: @rotton: From where it's called. I've placed it immediately after `\begin{document}` in order for the effect to be visible globally. You should also be able to use `\AtBeginDocument{\nonfrenchspacing}` within the preamble.